# How to extract image rotation from a PDF

Tags: pdf, image-processing, rotate

I'm extracting all the images from a bunch of scanned PDFs using `pdfimages`, in order to process and repackage them.

The problem is that some images are rotated 90° (either CW or CCW) and others are not. The original PDF re-rotates them on the page, so that all the pages show up straight, but the extracted images remain rotated.

I couldn't find an option in `pdfimages` to output the rotations, so that I could use them in a script.

Is there a way to extract this information?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if your PDF's are multi-page, so if they are then use [pdfTK](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) or [pdfSAM](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfsam/) to break them into single page PDF's, then use [The Gimp](https://www.gimp.org/) to rotate the images manually.

The other thing that you could is use a tool like [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) to automate the rotation, but you would probably have to separate the normal, CW, CCW pictures into different folders.

Comment: The actual problem is automatic recognition of the rotation, not how to rotate pages/images manually.